# Select template argument at runtime in C++

Tags: c++, templates, runtime, arguments

Suppose I have a set of functions and classes which are templated to use single (`float`) or `double` precision. Of course I could write just two pieces of bootstrap code, or mess with macros. But can I just switch template argument at runtime?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you can't switch template arguments at runtime, since templates are instantiated by the compiler at compile-time.  What you *can* do is have both templates derive from a common base class, always use the base class in your code, and then decide which derived class to use at runtime:

```
class Base
{
   ...
};

template <typename T>
class Foo : public Base
{
    ...
};

Base *newBase()
{
    if(some condition)
        return new Foo<float>();
    else
        return new Foo<double>();
}
```

Macros have the same problem as templates, in that they are expanded at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

Templates are a compile-time mechanism. BTW, macros are as well (strictly speaking - a preprocessing mechanism - that comes even before compilation).

Answer (score 2):

Templates are purely a compile time construct, the compiler will expand a template and create your class/function with the specified argument and directly translate that to code.

If you are trying to switch between `foo<float>` and `foo<double>` at runtime, you'll either need to use some metaprogramming trickery or just have seperate code paths for each.